# how to use highstock in ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, highcharts, ecmascript-next

here are an example of code that work, I create a graph

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

class test {
    constructor(){
        let chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                animation: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
            }]

        });
    }
}
```

now I want do a stockChart like https://jsfiddle.net/74vn5utd/

but I import it and its module

```
import StockChart from 'highcharts/highstock';
import datahc from 'highcharts/modules/data';
```

after that I load the module

```
datahc(StockChart);
```

and finally I call the chart and

```
StockChart.chart('container', {


    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: response.graph,
        tooltip: {
           valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

I have a regular graph, not a HighStock graph, I don't get it, what is wrong?
[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Highstock is a superset of Highcharts. You're loading highstock ok, but you're still using .chart(), which is wrong. It should be `StockChart.stockChart()` above

Answer (score 3):

You still use the **chart** constructor which creates regular chart.

Try to use **StockChart.stockChart('container, {...})**, where **stockChart** is a Highstock constructor.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v4qbyka6/

```
  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, that it isn't ecmascript :) in ecmascript it didn't recognise the function stockChart, please read my question well after answer, thanks

Comment: @Emiliano could you clarify what ecmascript means in your opinion then? Because as I know ECMAScript is a scripting-language specification standardized which was created to standardize JavaScript to help foster multiple independent implementations. In the parts of code which you have shared, you are using import and class methods which are JavaScript methods, just like the methods used in a demo which I sent you above. Have you tried to implement the code (constructor) which I suggested in the above post? Could you share a demo with your attempt?

Comment: the new version of javascript, javascript 2016 or 2017, my question already has an example, I don't know what kind of example you want.

Comment: @Emiliano ES6 was a major update which added new features to JS like introducing const, let, arrow functions, class etc. I don't understand why you suggest that the example which I shared to you is not an ECMAScript. If you need to use a class instead of a basic function, go ahead. I show you an example of how to import the HighStock as an ECMAScript module and create Highstock chart by using stockChart construction. Docs: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/#toc4